# Java: setText on a JLabel in Swing issues

Tags: java, swing, awt, jlabel

I have an issue setting a `JLabel`'s text using a method in the class creating the GUI from a different class calling that method. The method to set the `JLabel` is called outside the GUI but when called from inside the GUI class it works. I have tested the `getText()` method on the label after it is called from outside the GUI class and it shows that the label has been updated. I get that it is probably a paint issue or update issue with Swing but I'm at a loss of what to do. I have tried `repaint()` and `revalidate()` on the label and then panel that it is within. Here is my current code:

```
public void setStatusLabel(String statusEntered) {
    //Shows the variable statusEntered has been received 
    System.out.println(statusEntered);

    //Not working
    status_label.setText(statusEntered);

    //Used this to check if the label receives the data. It does.
    String status = status_label.getText();
    System.out.println(status);
}
```

And the context in which I am calling it. Setups a database connection

```
//GUI Class reference
MainWindow mainwindow = new MainWindow();

public void connect(){
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        String userName = "root";
        String password = "";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);

        //This works
        System.out.println("Connection Established");
        //The issue is with this guy
        mainwindow.setStatusLabel("Connection");
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Failed to connect to database");
        mainwindow.setStatusLabel("No connection");
    }
}
```

Any help with this would be awesome or if you have some links to suggestions, that would be awesome too! Thanks for the help.

Here is my main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MainWindow().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Isn't that will create 2 different instances of MainWindow?

Comment: @Yan: exactly so. He needs to pass the reference of this visualized MainWindow into his other class, perhaps by passing `this` in if the database class is created from within the MainWindow class. I'm waiting for more information from him about this.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is possibly one of reference -- your mainwindow variable in your GUI class may not be referring to the MainWindow object that is being displayed. Do you call `new MainWindow();` anywhere else in your code? If so, then you'd best pass a reference to the visualized MainWindow into this class above so that you can call methods on it that will result in something that can be seen.

For e.g.,

```
public class DatabaseConnection {
   // MainWindow mainwindow = new MainWindow();  *** don't do this ***
   MainWindow mainwindow;

   public DatabaseConnection(MainWindow mainwindow) {
      this.mainwindow = mainwindow; // pass in the reference in the constructor
   }

   public void connect() {
      Connection conn = null;

      // ... etc

      // now we can call methods on the actual visualized object
      mainwindow.setStatusLabel("Connection");
   }
```

Comment: Boom! My head just exploded so let me take a second to digest what you just said.
I call new MainWindow() from within my database connection class. 
That is the only time I call this. I get action from the method though. It shows me "Connection Established" in the "command line" area of the IDE and it updates the Label's text.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you don't call `new MainWindow();` from within the `public static void main(String[] args)` method?

Comment: No I am not positive. I do. With the recreated code above I get a nullPointerException.
Here is the main

   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainWindow().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

Comment: @Christopher: Well, where do you initialize the database connection class? Come on, you can figure this out if you think in terms of references.

Comment: Alright down and dirty. Here we go. I have three classes. A Main, MainWindow(GUI) and dbConnection(Database Connection). I initialize MainWindow from Main. I have methods in dbConnection but the method to connect is called from MainWindow on an ActionPerformed on a jButton (This will change eventually). The connect method calls a method from MainWindow which updates the JLabel.setText().

Comment: To re-iterate, **where do you initialize the database connection class?** Where do you call new on the database connection class? Please ask questions if this question of mine doesn't make sense as otherwise I don't really know how to ask this in any other way that you'll understand it better.

Comment: OK, now we're getting somewhere. Have the constructor accept a MainWindow parameter, as I show above, and then when you call new on the database connection class, pass `this` (the current MainWindow instance) into its constructor. Then it won't be null.

Comment: sigh... into the class's constructor. You will have to use the constructor's name for this to work.

Comment: Yea I got that. I'm a little slow. I inserted what you told but now how do I reference the connect method within the MainWindow class. Because before it was the no-no dbConnection connect = new dbConnection(); line. And then from within MainWindow I would connect.connect();

Comment: No idea what you're asking, sorry, and am going to be. Much luck. Read up on references to objects in Java.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels - Very nice! (+1 :) )

Comment: Apologies for my lack of education in this field and that you had to waste your time. Thank you for the help though.

Comment: You can accept this answer by clicking on the empty check mark to the left; see the [faq] for details.

Comment: Ok I finally understood what you were talking about now. It was a problem of reference.

Comment: @Christopher: you didn't waste my time, and sorry if I implied that you did. If you've learned about references, then this dialog was very much a success. Much luck in this project and your future in programming! /Pete

Comment: Is there anyway to delete this jackassery. I had woken up thinking about this all night and I guess I got ahead of myself. Not a morning person.

Comment: @Christopher: You can delete comments easily by the little white cross in the red circle that is to the right of the comment's time stamp. I recommend against deleting too much as some of the information might be helpful to others in the future who have a similar problem and find this thread in their search for a solution. Again, much luck!

Comment: So crazy to look back at this question and realize "How stupid"

Comment: @Christopher: please don't confuse ignorance with stupidity. The first we're born with and is cured by knowledge gained through study. The second, well, I don't know of any cure.

Answer (score 3):

what i have tried to do is that, you return the status of connection and print it on the mainWindow status_jlable, here you don't need to pass the reference of main window in the database class your just returning the status of connection and thats all you need.

```
public class MainWindows extends JFrame {

    private JLabel status_label;
    public MainWindows(){
        status_label  = new JLabel("Status");
    }

    public void setStatusLabel(String staus){
        status_label.setText(staus);    
    }
    /*.
     * 
     * your code for visualizing 
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .*/

    public static void main(String args[]){
        MainWindows mw = new MainWindows();

        //this will return true if the connection will estblished and will false if not
        mw.setStatusLabel("Connection established "+ new DatabaseConnection().connect());

    }

}
```

/////////////database class

```
   public class DatabaseConnection{


        public boolean connect(){
            Connection conn = null;


            // adding this new variable to get connection status;
            boolean returnStatus = false;  //default return false if connection established it will true .
            try {
                String userName = "root";
                String password = "";
                String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306";
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);

                //This works
                System.out.println("Connection Established");
                //The issue is with this guy
                returnStatus = true;  // making status true if connection is established

                return returnStatus;
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Failed to connect to database");
                return returnStatus;
            }
        }

    }
```